# Debugging Jquery slider click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-slider

Scenario: ASP.NET site. One of the ASPX page has the Jquery slider implemented by another developer.
The slider works fine in Dev enviornment but not in production. The other developer tried to check in production but getting no success so far.

Basically the slider has PREV and NEXT arrow buttons. They slide in DEV but in production they do not.

What are the things to consider (or debug) as to why it is not working in production ? (works fine in dev).

I am new to Jquery and any help is appreciated. I want to paste the source but I see lot of files.

Looking for some directions here.

Thanks.

Comment: Check that the dev and production environments match exactly, specifically make sure that all javascript src files are in the correct places.  Also, check the console in the production environment for error messages, either at startup or when you click one of the problematic buttons.

Comment: I have checked couple of times to make sure files match between DEV and production. Don't know at this moment what is the mismatch. Are there any must or mandatory files (or keywords) that I must check for?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?  Also, in the element view of the debugger, go to the head and click on the urls for the included javascript files to make sure it can open them.  Is it possible for you to supply a link to the production server so I/we can have a look as well?  I'm afraid the question is like "how long is a piece of string".

Comment: @Archer:What do you mean by 'check console for errors'?. I am not sure. All links worked fine in production. The production site is yet to be made public facing.

Comment: The browser will most likely have a development/debugging console in it - usually press F12 to get it.  There will be various tabs, but one in particular is called "console" and it will show errors and warnings caused by the client-side code of your application.

Comment: @Archer:Console didn't show anything and said no errors. I am tryin to trap the PREVIOUS & NEXT within slider so that I can see what is happening in DEV & Production. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: @Archer: I have the site now on a public facing server. Please let me know if I can share the URL with you.

Comment: Amend the original post and put the URL in there - it will make sure more people see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the IE developer tools to debug and found the issues. There were javascript errors and I fixed them.